# How can I connect Netezza to CDH 3 cluster?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, netezza, sqoop

How can I import data from Netezza to my CDH 3 cluster. Can we do it with MapReduce or Sqoop. Can Sqoop support data import from Netezza to CDH 3 cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Sqoop uses [any jdbc driver](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/archive/cdh/4-x/4-7-1/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_13_7.html). Netezza has a [jdbc driver](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.1.0/com.ibm.nz.datacon.doc/c_datacon_installing_jdbc_unix_linux.html?lang=en).